# How to find periodic solutions using a graphing calculator

Tags: recurrence-relations, dynamical-systems

We have the model $X_{n+1} = 4\left(X_n - \dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2$ with a given $X_0$ on the domain $[0,1]$. We have the following question:

*Use your graphing calculator to figure out if there are periodic solutions with period 2 and if yes; calculate for which $X_0$ this is the case.*

So to find period 2 solutions I rewrote and got:

$$ x = 4\left(\,4±\left(\,x-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2 - \dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2$$

But I need some hints on how to continue with this problems. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The equation is $x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$. A period-2 solution means $x_{n+2} = x_n$. So you can find these by solving $x = f(f(x))$. To do this, plot $x$ and $f(f(x))$ and see where they cross (they cross **iff** $x=f(f(x))$).

In your case, $f(x) = 4\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2$, so $f(f(x)) = 4\left( 4\left( x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}$.

Plot $x, 4\left( 4\left( x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}$ on $[0,1]$ and look for where they cross.

Four solutions are apparent (as expected, since you are solving a quartic).

This gives:

[image]

Also, you could note that the equation for the period-2 fixed points is $x=4\,( 4 ( x-\frac{1}{2})^{2}-\frac{1}{2} )^{2}$, which simplifies to 
$64x^4-128x^3+80x^2-17x+1=0$. This can be factored as $(x-1)(4x-1)(16 x^2-12 x+1) = 0$, so two solutions are obvious, and the other two straightforward to compute.

**Addendum**: Here is another graph that may be more illustrative: The two fixed points (period-1 solutions) at $\frac{1}{4},1$ are clear. (Period-1 solutions are period-2 solutions, of course). The period-2 orbit is also clear.

[image]

Comment: Without really thinking I did this, but then I realized I had no idea why I was doing it. I still don't. What do the intersections represent? How does this help with finding period 2 solutions?

Comment: I added a short note at the top, hopefully that clarifies.

Comment: Yes, I understand the short note, thanks. I also know that the solution $x = \dfrac{1}{4}$ and $x = 1$ are invalid since those are period 1 solutions. However, I'm wondering how you can find the right values of $X_0$ from these intersections. That's what's puzzling me

Comment: Well, a period-1 solution is, of course, a period-2 solution. I'm not sure what you are asking about $x_0$. You can estimate the values by looking at the graph crossings. Is that what you are puzzled about?

Comment: For which $x_0$ are there actually period 2 solutions? I know the intersections, at which $X_0$ can we actually witness them (on [0,1])? For example, if you use $x=\dfrac{1}{4}$ you get a period 1 solution, and I'm looking for specific period 2 solutions (eventhough in theory every period 1 solution is a period n solution)

Comment: Nevermind all comments, I forgot to fill in the intersections into the original function again. Thanks for your help (p.s. I didn't give you the -1, I would give you a +1 but I have no clue how to do that)

Comment: @Lolz Just click on the uparrow at the left of the answer.

Comment: @Lolz: No problem at all. It would help if the downvoters explained why the downvote.